# How would I properly call this list from another class?

Tags: java

I have a modest programming background, but I am totally green to Java. I inherited some Java code at work, and I am simply trying to call this list properly.

Assistance appreciated.

```
public class CallTestClassList {

try { <how do I properly call the list from TestClass?> }

}
public class TestClass {

    public List TestList() {

                String s = null;
                List cData = new ArrayList();
                String[] Warning = null;
                String[] Error = null;
                int flag = 0;
    }
    return cData;
}
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Syntax errors are off topic here. And there is nothing in this code that resembles Java syntax.

Comment: Do you mean _invoke the method `TestList()` which has a return type of `List` on an instance of type `TestClass`_?

Comment: Yes, That is basically what I am asking.. I tried researching it on my own, but Java is much different than other languages I have used. I understand its a very basic question... and apologize, but I appreciate the replies.

Answer (score 0):

```
new TestClass().TestList();
```

At least, that's what I assume is the answer since I don't know what sort of constructors `TestClass` has.

Comment: I apologize I was trying to strip down the code to the bare essentials to maintain work confidentiality, but looks like I stripped to much.. Maybe the edit I made above to the code snippet helps identify constructor. Thanks!